# iOS, AutoLayout Constraint: Center X Constrain is moving view to right?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

For some reason my autolayout is not centering my view as I want it to.

[image]

In this picture, I have added the constraint for 13 points to he left so that it will appear OK on the screen, however if I leave the constraints to 0, it will of course be 13 points to the right, not centered with Always On Top. 
Why is this happening?

This picture bellow shows a constant of 13, making it look just how I want it.

This picture is with a constant of 0. [image][image]

I managed to figure out 13 was the right distance it was being offset by by just eyeballing it. But shouldn't a constant of 0 make it perfectly center aligned?

Comment: Why is this happening what? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Can you show two images: Firstly with the constraints with 0 constant and secondly with the 13 constant. Then explain what is wrong and what you would expect. Currently, it's difficult to understand what exact problem you are having.

Comment: I can't tell exactly what is wrong but the centering relationship is to a view called `Always On Top` but I would have expected it to be to the `Superview`. If `Always On Top` is slightly larger than expected or partly off-screen or not centred then your controls will not be centred correctly either.

Comment: @Andy How do you set width of `controls`? And why `Always on top` is a `UICollectionViewCell`?

Comment: @orkenstein im trying to achieve the same effect as Spotify with this project. https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout/

Comment: @orkenstein my nib would be the header of the collection view, and im setting the width with constraints? Is there an eaiser way to achieve that same parallax effect? I cant seem to get this to work.

Comment: @Andy, possibly, it conflicts somehow with UICollectionView insets somehow. If you want, you can share kinda example project. I'll examine it.